# How to get the query parameters in nock callback

Tags: node.js, nock

I want to access the query parameter in nock reply callback.

The request object that is exposed contains the path that has them as a string. But I would like to access them as a map so that I will not have to deal with parsing the string

```
const scope = nock('http://www.google.com')
  .get('/cat-poems')
  .reply(function(uri, requestBody) {
    console.log('path:', this.req.path)
    console.log('headers:', this.req.headers)
    // ...
  })
```

I would expect the query params to be a separate map that I can access
Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this.req` inside a reply function is an instance of a [`ClientRequest`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) that has been slightly modified.

Unfortunately for your use case, `ClientRequest` does not provide an easy way to access just the query params. But you do have access to the full path, from which you can parse the query params out.

```
const nock = require('nock')
const http = require('http')
const url = require('url')

const scope = nock('http://www.google.com')
  .get('/cat-poems')
  .query(true)
  .reply(function(uri, requestBody) {
    const parsed = new url.URL(this.req.path, 'http://example.com')
    console.log('query params:', parsed.searchParams)
    return [200, 'OK']
  })

const req = http.get('http://www.google.com/cat-poems?page=12')

// output >> query params: URLSearchParams { 'page' => '12' }
```

The object being logged is a [`URLSearchParams`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams) instance.

Using the [`URL`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_url) constructor is the preferred method over [`url.parse`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) now, so I've used that for the example. Keep in mind that `URL` won't parse relative paths alone, it requires an origin, but since you don't care about the host in the end it can be a dummy value (hence the use of "example.com").